# Setup 4 head video card and monitors?

Tags: multiple-monitors, xubuntu

I'd like to get the 4 head setup on my machine that runs two different video cards:

```
 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV620 LE 
 NVIDIA Corporation GF119 [NVS 310]
```

I got two monitors working, but the other 2 are completely blank. Video cards are installed and everything is hooked up. xrandr:

DP-0 connected primary 1280x1024+1280+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 376mm x 301mm
   1280x1024      60.0*+   75.0
   1152x864       75.0
   1024x768       75.0     60.0
   800x600        75.0     60.3
   640x480        75.0     59.9
DP-1 connected 1280x1024+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 376mm x 301mm
   1280x1024      60.0*+   75.0
   1152x864       75.0
   1024x768       75.0     60.0
   800x600        75.0     60.3
   640x480        75.0     59.9
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
Only one graphic card works at the time, but not both. It is quite easy to do so on windows, but not so much on xubuntu 14.04 lts.

Anyone ran into similar issues?

Comment: Please clarify which monitors connected to which graphics card are currently working.

Comment: 4 dell monitors - 2 monitors are connected to Nvidia and 2 others are connected to Radeon. The two monitors that are working are currently hooked up to Nvidia card.